# What is meant by operation mode of a resistor?

Tags: power, resistors, datasheet

The [datasheet](https://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs2/2024/1/19/22/13/39/392980/vsh_/manual/tnpw_e3.pdf) refers to different operating modes for the resistor with the below note- What does it really mean?

**Note:** The presented operation modes do not refer to different types of resistors, but actually show examples of different loads, that lead to different film temperatures and different achievable load-life stability (drift) of the resistance value.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunate 'marketBS' dishonest use of the word 'advanced', which makes it sound 'better', but really means 'reckless'. Cook the resistor, and it will drift and fail earlier. When a professional engineer, I routinely used resistors up to only 50% of their rated power, no more, so their failure rate could be essentially ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation modes relate to the life expectancy and resistance drifts. Each mode refers to a set of operation modes and a resultant life expectancy along with a resistance change (drift). So these are "options" provided by the manufacturer for different "expectations".

**GENERAL** mode, for example, refers to operation conditions such as up to 125 °C film temperature and a power dissipation of up to 270 mW for 1206-case resistors. Under these conditions, the expected life time would be 225 khrs (20+ yrs) with a resistance change (drift) of up to 0.3%.

If you are happy with lower life expectancy, such as up to 1000 hrs (40 days) then **ADVANCED** mode which corresponds to half a watt along with a permissible film temperature of up to 175°C is an option. If you check the table again, you'll see that ADVANCED mode is not available for 1210-case resistors. That's probably because the life expectancy becomes less than 1000 hrs.

So, basically, with different conditions, expect different "life expectancies" and "resistance drifts".

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the numbers, you will get better stability specs if you don't use the resistor at the maximum rated power but with less power.

The chart simply says how much resistance stabiliy you can expect at different power dissipation levels.